# Insert into another database only inserting 1 record

Tags: objective-c, sql, sqlite

I am trying to take the data from one table and move it over to another table. First I select all the records from the Items table in the db_data database. Then for every record that is in that table it should insert it into the Items table in the db_information database. I am only getting one record written into my Items table in the db_information database. I have 8 records in the Items table in the db_data database. So why is it not inserting all my records?

```
strSQL = @"SELECT GID FROM Items";
chrStmt = [strSQL UTF8String];
if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(db_data, chrStmt, -1, &cmpStmt, NULL) == SQLITE_OK){
    while(sqlite3_step(cmpStmt) == SQLITE_ROW){
        char *val = (char *)sqlite3_column_text(cmpStmt, 0);
        NSString *strVal = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:val];
        strSQL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"INSERT INTO Items (GID) VALUES ('%@')", strVal];
        chrStmt = [strSQL UTF8String];
        if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(db_information, chrStmt, -1, &cmpStmt, NULL) == SQLITE_OK){
            sqlite3_step(cmpStmt);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that maybe you are falsely reusing your variables `strSQL`, `chrStmt` and especially `cmpStmt`. This is both used in the `while` loop condition and main body.

Try using separate variables for the other database.